# Python basemap - read shapefile given in map projection coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, map-projections

I am trying to read a shapefile of San Francisco Police Departments (https://data.sfgov.org/Public-Safety/SFPD-Districts-Zipped-Shapefile-Format-/8yyx-6uur) via `basemap`.

When i use the `basemap.readshapefile` method, I get the error

```
shapefile must have lat/lon vertices  - it looks like this one has vertices
    in map projection coordinates. You can convert the shapefile to geographic
    coordinates using the shpproj utility from the shapelib tools
    (http://shapelib.maptools.org/shapelib-tools.html)
```

is there a way to read or convert map projection coordinates in python (since i dont want to use the C-Library given in the error)?

Comment: Can [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77529/how-to-find-and-apply-reprojection-parameters) be helpful? Also, take a look at `pyproj` module